# PowerShell: The difference in parentheses expressions

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I've been experimenting with the different forms of operators/expressions involving parentheses, but I can't find an explanation for an interaction I'm running into.  Namely, `( )` and `$( )` (subexpression operator) are not equivalents.  Nor is it equivalent to `@( )` (array operator).  For most cases this doesn't matter, but when trying to evaluate the contents of the parentheses as an expression (for example, variable assignment), they're different.  I'm looking for an answer on *what* parentheses are doing when they aren't explicitly one operator or another and the `about_` documents don't call this out.

---

```
($var = Test-Something) # -> this passes through
$($var = Test-Something) # -> $null
@($var = Test-Something) # -> $null
```

---

*[about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1)*

Comment: `($var = Test-Something)` is running the code as a single unit of work.
`$($var = Test-Something)` runs it as a unit of work but treats the value as a variable. `@()` single bit of work but treats the value as a array.

Comment: @ArcSet Not quite.  `@()` will return all expressions contained as an array (even one item).  `$()` will take multiple returns as an array, otherwise a scalar (variable, essentially).  `()` appears to work the same as `$()` except in the example I laid out above except you cannot have multiple statements/expressions contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#array-subexpression-operator--) and [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--) operators, the parentheses are simply needed syntactically. Their only purpose is to wrap the expression the operator should be applied on.

Some examples:

```
# always return array, even if no child items found
@(Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.log").Count

# if's don't work inside regular parentheses
$(if ($true) { 1 } else { 0 })
```

When you put (only) parentheses around a variable assignment, this is called [variable squeezing](https://ridicurious.com/2019/03/07/powershell-variable-squeezing/).

```
$v = 1 # sets v to 1 and returns nothing
($v = 1) # sets v to 1 and returns assigned value
```

You can get the pass-thru version for all your examples by combining variable squeezing with the subexpression operator syntax (that is, adding a second pair of parentheses):

```
($var = Test-Something)
$(($var = Test-Something))
@(($var = Test-Something))
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer and had forgotten I asked this question. In another question, it was revealed it's called the"grouping operator" (I think quoted from a PS dev) and doesn't have associated docs

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Thanks for the input, didn't realize it had a name. True, the documentation doesn't mention variable squeezing in the additional grouping operator behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

$( ) is unique.  You can put multiple statements inside it:

```
$(echo hi; echo there) | measure | % count

2
```

You can also put things you can't normally pipe from, like foreach () and if, although the values won't come out until the whole thing is finished.  This allows you to put multiple statements anywhere that just expects a value.

```
$(foreach ($i in 1..5) { $i } ) | measure | % count

5
```

```
$x = 10
if ( $( if ($x -lt 5) { $false } else { $x } ) -gt 20)
{$false} else {$true}
```

```
for ($i=0; $($y = $i*2; $i -lt 5); $i++) { $y }
```

```
$err = $( $output = ls foo ) 2>&1
```